# Graduation attire - masters hood while receiving an associate degree

Tags: etiquette, graduation, outward-appearance

I earned a MS degree a while back.  I went back to school for another degree that happens to a "lower" degree...associates of science.  Can I wear my Master's hood while getting the AS degree at graduation?

Comment: You have not said which country etc. Might make a difference...

Comment: Usually if you're receiving a degree, you wear the attire corresponding to the degree you're receiving. Why would you want to wear your master's attire?

Comment: At both the universities I've attended, the graduate attire was stipulated when submitting my "intent to graduate" (and yes, it was based of the degree received in both cases as observed by @ff524). So in this case I'd ask your university's bookstore or registrar

Comment: For what it's worth, my wife recently graduated with her masters (USA) and wore her undergraduate gown. No one noticed.

Comment: I'd avoid doing this regardless of whether it is officially allowed.  You motives may be completely pure (maybe you just want to celebrate both degrees, or enjoy wearing the fanciest regalia to which you are entitled), but it could come across as denigrating the associate degree by seeming too eager to make sure everyone knows that you have a higher and more prestigious degree.

Comment: This depends entirely on the regulations of your university.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician That depends entirely on the university. For example, at Cambridge, the only correct graduation attire is the gown associated with the highest degree you already hold, along with the hood of the highest degree you're receiving that day. (So, for example, I received my BA wearing my undergrad gown and a BA hood, and my MA and PhD on the same day, wearing the BA gown and PhD hood.)

Comment: If you don't specify the country and the university, this question is really meaningless: in certain countries you can wear whatever you wish at any graduation.

Comment: This is an awesome question.  I think you should do it. Look at it this way - successful lay people sometimes get honorary PhDs, right?  They're not shy about showing that off. So why should you be shy about wearing your appropriately awarded, university-backed regalia?  ...but maybe clear it with the appropriate office.